# OutofRange Error when retraining by google object detection API

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning

I am trying to use google object detection API for retraining pre-trained network [following this link](https://github.com/salekd/santa/wiki/Transfer-learning-with-SSD-MobileNet-v1).

but I faced with the following error: the main error backs to

```
self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access
```

I can't figure that where were this error is related to. I am using ubuntu 18, python 3.6.  I will appreciate for your help and comments. 
I attached the full log here:

```
 INFO:tensorflow:Caught OutOfRangeError. Stopping Training. FIFOQueue '_6_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2[component_types=[DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](prefetch_queue)]]

Caused by op 'prefetch_queue_Dequeue', defined at:
  File "/home/tree/MEGAsync/PyProj_right/TransferFineTuneLAB/tensorflow_toy_detector/train.py", line 206, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/tree/MEGAsync/PyProj_right/TransferFineTuneLAB/tensorflow_toy_detector/train.py", line 202, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "/home/tree/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 285, in train
    clones = model_deploy.create_clones(deploy_config, model_fn, [input_queue])
  File "/home/tree/models/research/slim/deployment/model_deploy.py", line 193, in create_clones
    outputs = model_fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/tree/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 177, in _create_losses
    train_config.use_multiclass_scores)
  File "/home/tree/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 122, in get_inputs
    read_data_list = input_queue.dequeue()
  File "/home/tree/models/research/object_detection/core/batcher.py", line 111, in dequeue
    batched_tensors = self._queue.dequeue()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/data_flow_ops.py", line 440, in dequeue
    self._queue_ref, self._dtypes, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_data_flow_ops.py", line 3734, in queue_dequeue_v2
    timeout_ms=timeout_ms, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 787, in _apply_op_helper
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 3392, in create_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1718, in __init__
    self._traceback = self._graph._extract_stack()  # pylint: disable=protected-access

OutOfRangeError (see above for traceback): FIFOQueue '_6_prefetch_queue' is closed and has insufficient elements (requested 1, current size 0)
     [[Node: prefetch_queue_Dequeue = QueueDequeueV2[component_types=[DT_STRING, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, DT_INT32, DT_FLOAT, ..., DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_INT32, DT_STRING, DT_INT32], timeout_ms=-1, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](prefetch_queue)]]

INFO:tensorflow:Finished training! Saving model to disk.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/tree/MEGAsync/PyProj_right/TransferFineTuneLAB/tensorflow_toy_detector/train.py", line 206, in <module>
    tf.app.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/platform/app.py", line 126, in run
    _sys.exit(main(argv))
  File "/home/tree/MEGAsync/PyProj_right/TransferFineTuneLAB/tensorflow_toy_detector/train.py", line 202, in main
    worker_job_name, is_chief, FLAGS.train_dir)
  File "/home/tree/models/research/object_detection/trainer.py", line 410, in train
    saver=saver)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/slim/python/slim/learning.py", line 784, in train
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/supervisor.py", line 828, in stop
    ignore_live_threads=ignore_live_threads)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/coordinator.py", line 389, in join
    six.reraise(*self._exc_info_to_raise)
  File "/home/tree/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/six.py", line 693, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/training/queue_runner_impl.py", line 252, in _run
    enqueue_callable()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1244, in _single_operation_run
    self._call_tf_sessionrun(None, {}, [], target_list, None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 1409, in _call_tf_sessionrun
    run_metadata)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: /home/tree/MEGAsync/PyProj_right/TransferFineTuneLAB/tensorflow_toy_detector/tfdata.tfrecord; No such file or directory
     [[Node: parallel_read/ReaderReadV2 = ReaderReadV2[_device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0"](parallel_read/TFRecordReaderV2, parallel_read/filenames)]]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. It simply related to the misusing of data protocol. main data protocol was coco but I tried to feed wrong data set.
Therefore the errors were because that it can not read any data.